# want to display positive and negative values in different columns thru a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one column table with negative and positive values and want to display positive and negative values in different columns thru a single query.

```
Column
-10000
-17000
 16000
 25000
```

output should be like

```
A        B     
-----------------
-10000   16000
-17000   25000
```

I am using oracle and pl sql developer.

Comment: @Alex Aza: The rest of the Oracle community on SO frowns on tagging as PLSQL when it's not used to answer the question.

Comment: How do you know to put 16000 along side of -10000, and so on?

Comment: And what do you expect to happen when there are unequal counts of positive and negative numbers?

Comment: this should not close as this also has the solution as i posted...

please check this solution...

Answer (score 3):

```
select decode(sign(col),1,col) positive_value
      , decode(sign(col),-1,col) negative_value
      , decode(sign(col),0,col) zero_value
from tbl_name
```

i dont know whether this will work or not but once try it..

Answer (score 1):

HI sara ,

just try this one

```
SELECT T1.POSITIVE_VALUE, T2.negetive_value 
FROM (select COL positive_value, ROWNUM C1 FROM TEST_1 WHERE COL >= 0) T1 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT COL negetive_value, ROWNUM C2 FROM TEST_1 WHERE COL < 0) T2
ON (T1.C1 = T2.C2);
```

Comment: SORRY FOR PREVIOUS POST..
AND THANKS FOR THIS EDITION

Comment: Now that I can corrected the LT and GT operators this code will provide the required output.

Comment: @APC:
please tell me about LT and GT what you were telling about in your previous comment

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution but only if number of positive and negative numbers is same.

```
select a.column as negative, b.column as non_negative from table a, table b where a.column<0 and b.column>=0;
```

Where of course, `column` is your column name and `table` is your table name.