# Need to get the output as positive and negative numbers from one column into different columns from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, multiple-columns

I need a solution for the scenario below:

**TableA**

```
col1
2
4
-6
-5
4
-2
5
2
```

The above tableA is my source, i want the output as:

```
Positive      Negative
2              -6
4              -5
4              -2
5
2
```

The output that I am getting is as below:

```
Positive      Negative
2              NULL
4              NULL
4              NULL
5              NULL
2              NULL
NULL           -6
NULL           -5
NULL           -2
```

This is the query that I have tried:

```
SELECT pos.col2 AS 'Positive',neg.col2 AS 'negative'
FROM
(SELECT col2 FROM colum1 WHERE col2 < 0) neg FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT col2 FROM colum1 WHERE col2 > 0) pos
ON pos.col2 = neg.col2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210773/want-to-display-positive-and-negative-values-in-different-columns-thru-a-single

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (col INT)

INSERT INTO @temp (col)
VALUES (2), (4), (-6), (-5), (4), (-2), (5), (2)

SELECT Positive, Negative 
FROM (
    SELECT Positive = col, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0) 
    FROM @temp
    WHERE col >= 0
) t
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT Negative = col, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0)  
    FROM @temp
    WHERE col < 0
) t2 on t.RowNum = t2.RowNum
```

Output -

```
Positive    Negative
----------- -----------
2           -6
4           -5
4           -2
5           NULL
2           NULL
```

Comment: Hi Devart, I did get the required output, but can you please explain me what does that ORDER BY 1/0 does?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0)` - suppress the sort rows